# MLPACK | Compile Time Issue | Linux

Tags: g++, mlpack

I have followed [this](https://www.mlpack.org/doc/stable/doxygen/build.html) documentation to set up mlpack on my pc.
I have compiled the [Covariance Computation](https://www.mlpack.org/doc/stable/doxygen/sample.html) code.

```
g++ covariance.cc -o a -fopenmp -std=c++11
```

After compiling I got the following errors.

[image]
[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue Resolved**

```
g++ covariance.cc -o a -fopenmp -lmlpack -larmadillo
```

If you still get error check if armadillo prerequisites, BLAS or OPENBLAS and LAPACK are installed and configured.

```
sudo apt install cmake libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev
```

You can download the latest and stable version of Armadillo from [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html).

[Blog](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/03/24/getting-started-armadillo-cpp-linear-algebra-windows-mac-linux/) on armadillo installation instruction for different OS.